# MS Sql Server - Function not compiling because of selecting from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I made a function that will return the sum of the column from a table which is the result of a query to another table. It's easier to understand when looking at the code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getPatientMorphineEquivalentDose]
(
    @patientID int
)
RETURNS INT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT SUM(j.MilligramMorphineEquivalent) FROM 
    (
        SELECT i.Mg * i.[Morphine Equivalent (mg)] AS MilligramMorphineEquivalent
        FROM
        (
            SELECT PatientMedication.Mg, Medication.[Morphine Equivalent (mg)]
            FROM PatientMedication
            INNER JOIN Medication 
            ON PatientMedication.MedicationID = Medication.Id
            WHERE PatientMedication.PatientID = @patientID
        ) AS i
    ) AS j )
END
```

I have very little experience with Sql Server so I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong, but from what I researched online this should work. I tried it with a stored procedure as well and it still would not compile.

Comment: Be sure to post your error 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify which error you got, but since you're defining your function with `schemabinding`, I expect you got an error like:

> Cannot schema bind function 'dbo.getPatientMorphineEquivalentDose' because name 'PatientMedication' is invalid for schema binding. Names must be in two-part format and an object cannot reference itself.

When you use `schemabinding`, you are expected to prefix the object names with the owner. Notice what the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) says (emphasis mine):

> A function can be schema bound only if the following conditions are true:
>
> - The function is a Transact-SQL function.
> - The user-defined functions and views referenced by the function are also schema-bound.
> - ***The objects referenced by the function are referenced using a two-part name.***
> - The function and the objects it references belong to the same database.
> - The user who executed the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement has `REFERENCES` permission on the database objects that the function references.

So assuming your tables are owned by `dbo`, make sure to prefix the 2 referenced tables in the query (`dbo.PatientMedication` and `dbo.Medication`):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getPatientMorphineEquivalentDose]
(
    @patientID int
)
RETURNS INT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT SUM(j.MilligramMorphineEquivalent) FROM 
    (
        SELECT i.Mg * i.[Morphine Equivalent (mg)] AS MilligramMorphineEquivalent
        FROM
        (
            SELECT PatientMedication.Mg, Medication.[Morphine Equivalent (mg)]
            FROM dbo.PatientMedication
            INNER JOIN dbo.Medication 
            ON PatientMedication.MedicationID = Medication.Id
            WHERE PatientMedication.PatientID = @patientID
        ) AS i
    ) AS j )
END
```

By the way, unrelated to your error, but the query can be simplified:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getPatientMorphineEquivalentDose]
(
    @patientID int
)
RETURNS INT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT sum(pm.Mg * m.[Morphine Equivalent (mg)])
            FROM dbo.PatientMedication pm
            INNER JOIN dbo.Medication m
            ON pm.MedicationID = m.Id
            WHERE pm.PatientID = @patientID)
END
```

Comment: Thank you, solved my problem perfectly! Also I really appreciate the simplification of my query.